# bridge networking using pppo

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bridge

I amusing reliance netconnect from pppo.
I have added vbox and vm in it. vm can access outside machines but other cant to vm.
can anyone tell me how to bridge in ppp0?

Answer (score 0):

You can't bridge a ppp connection, sorry:  You can only route the ip packets.

If one direction works and the other does not, you'll have to look:

- Is NAT used?
- Are the routes set up correctly?
- Are there firewalls, how configured?